# How to determine and print the longest command line argument in java?

Tags: java, for-loop, command-line, arguments

I've been assigned to write a program that reads the command line arguments and prints out the longest argument stated. I'm definitely a novice here and don't even know where to start. Here's all I've got. I know I'm gonna need a for loop for this.

```
public class Assignment2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("You need to pass in at least one argument to run this program."); }
    if (args.length > 1) {
        for (int i = 0; int < args[].length(); i++) {
            System.out.println("The longest argument is " + i + " " + args[i]);
        }
```

I know everything I have inside the for loop right there isn't going to work. It's just stuff I threw onto it hoping it'd stick. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command-line arguments in java are stored in a String array. You can simply loop through all of these Strings and compare the lengths.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("You need to pass in at least one argument to run this program."); }
    if (args.length >= 1) {
        String longestArg = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length(); i++) {
            if (args[i].length() > longestArg.length()) {
                longestArg = args[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The longest argument is " + longestArg + " with length " + longestArg.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the args[] array using a for loop with an int i. Access each member based on the value of i:

```
args[i]
```

Save the first string, args[0], into a separate string object, called s (or whatever you like).

Then, for each string in the array (here is where the loop begins), compare to s using the length method:

```
s.length() > args[i].length()
```

If the args[i] string is larger, save it in s. At the end, print out s.

You could, optionally, use a for each loop, rather than a standard for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the args array, note the index with longest argument.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int longest=0,index=0;
     if(args.length>0)
     {
          for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++)
          if(args[i].length()>longest)
          {
                longest=args[i].length();
                index=i;
          }
          System.out.println(args[index]);
     }

}
```